# change the css via php

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to change the css property?

Ok, I have this code.

```
<form action="changecss.php" method="POST">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
which one do you want to change :
</td>
<td>
<select type="text" name="thecolorselect">
<option value="background">Background</option>
<option value="anchor">Achor</option>
<option value="paragraph">Paragraph</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
Current attributes:
</td>
<td>
<select name="attr">
<!-- here will be listed the current attributes of the item -->
</select>
</td>
<td>
Change into:
</td>
<td>
<select type="text" name="thecolorinput">
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="blue">blue</option>
<option value="yellow">yellow</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button name="changecsspropertynow">Change the background color now</button>
</form>
```

so now, when a user hit the button the specified css property should be change as what it was set on the form, for example: which one do you want to change : Background, Current attributes: Background, Change into: Blue. This is just an expirement and I just dont know how to do it, all i have is the idea right now and no codes. thank you in advance if someone help here.

Comment: Why do you think this is a good idea to do with PHP? what is your goal regarding your PHP?

Comment: I would like to suggest to use jQuery for this

Comment: would you not be better off changing the colours using javascript and save the user a page refresh? Assuming you've got extra php code we can't see to handle the form post?

Comment: @JPHellemons You're also one of those guys suggesting jQuery for every question regarding something happening in the browser?

Comment: @Cristoph, YES! LOL. no seriously, if you change css which is just UI for the client. I would use jQuery because of the nice selectors and because it does not put a load on your server. and does not require a postback etc.

Comment: @Christoph. Are you one of the guys suggesting changing css on the server side?

Comment: @gdoron Depending on the situation, why not? Perhaps its a logged in user and his choice should be stored in a database with his personal settings? Nonetheless i dislike suggesting loading a 90kB framework for doing stuff i can write in 3 lines normal JS.

Comment: @Christoph. 1. He tagged the question `jQuery`. 2. There are better ways of custom appearance not invoving server side requests.

Comment: `select` tag does not have an attribute `type` http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Comment: @JPHellemons posting w3fools links isn't professional either^^ http://w3fools.com/

Comment: Yes, this thing is suit using jquery however, how i am going to save those css property modifications into the actual css, i mean save the changes that have been specified into the css file.

Comment: @gdoron so, now that we know that he wants to store the altered CSS, I'd like to have a bulletproof solution of how to solve this without server-interaction `There are better ways of custom appearance not invoving server side requests` :-D

Comment: @Christoph. I would use Asp.Net-mvc, to render the HTML at the server with his classes the user wants. Not sending request to server to change it. I'm in a hurry, sorry, we can continue later... sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up the discussions regarding your question:

There (could be) no need to do this serverside. You can read the values of those options via Javascript and change the styles accordingly.

You only need php, if you want to remember those settings for the user in a database or something like that.

It is even easier, if you use jQuery ( ty  @ JP Hellemons :-D ).

Update: [try it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/4mpWs/3/)

If you want to store those settings, you could:

1. store it clientside via cookie or local|session-Storage
2. send an ajax-request an store it serverside
3. actually indeed submit the form and process it serverside.

every method has it's pros and cons, so it depends on you, what you want to do.

Comment: but i want to save those configurations into the actual css file or save the change base on the specified settings into the real current css.

Comment: Yes, this thing is suit using jquery however, how i am going to save those css property modifications into the actual css, i mean save the changes that have been specified into the css file.

Comment: @user1292042 then you simply need to submit the form, evaluate it on serverside and save the changes. Take a look at phps `$_POST` and how to save it to a database or a file.